# difficulty in coverting a forOf loop expression to array iterable statement

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom, iterable

I'm currently having difficulties converting a forOf loop statement in my weather app to an array iterable expression. The forOf statement works, but .eslintrc.JSON is flagging it as a no-restricted-syntax error.

**The Given array:**

```
 const results = [

    { elementId: '#result-temp', value: `${temp}°` },

    { elementId: '#result-place', value: place },

    { elementId: '#result-weather', value: weatherTitle },

    { elementId: '#result-weather-desc', value: weatherDesc },

    { elementId: '#result-feeling', value: `${feeling}°` },

    { elementId: '#result-humidity', value: `${humidity}%` },

    { elementId: '#result-pressure', value: `${pressure}mb` },

    { elementId: '#result-mintemp', value: `${minTemp}°` },

    { elementId: '#result-maxtemp', value: `${maxTemp}°` },

  ];
```

**The forOf expression that works:**

```
  for (const { elementId, value } of results) {

    document.querySelector(elementId).innerText = value;

  }
```

**My use of forEach but doesn't work**

```
 results.forEach( value => {

  document.querySelector(elementId).innerText = value;
  
  })
}
```

I have searched the internet and read a lot of documents for ideas before reaching out here. Pls, what's am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not destructuring the second time:

Try this:

```
results.forEach(({ elementId, value }) => {
  document.querySelector(elementId).innerText = value;
})
```

Considering your snippet

```
results.forEach( value => {

  document.querySelector(elementId).innerText = value;
  
  })
```

the `value` above will be each item(which is an object having two properties) of the array.